# printing xml tags attributes with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
    <pizzas attribute="CAT">
        <pizza>
            <name>Tomato &amp; Cheese</name>
            <small>5.50</small>
            <large>9.75</large>
        </pizza>
    </pizzas>
</menu>
```

i want to print out the attribute in the pizzas element, i've used :

```
<xsl:value-of select="/menu/pizzas/@attribute"/>
```

but it dosen't print anything

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong there (other than you're missing the closing `</pizzas></menu>` which I presume is a copy/paste issue)

Comment: Please note, that Peter has added the closing tags since my comment - I personally do not approve of editing code or data without the OP's approval, as that might mask an actual problem and send people on a wild-goose chase.

Answer (score 2):

I'm building on Peter's answer in order to address one of the comments that is not factually correct.  You asked if you *have* to use the instructions and Peter said "yes", but in fact that is not correct.

Using Peter's input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
  <pizzas attribute="CAT">
    <pizza>
        <name>Tomato &amp; Cheese</name>
        <small>5.50</small>
        <large>9.75</large>
    </pizza>
  </pizzas>
</menu>
```

You get the following result, which is the same as Peter's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><output>CAT</output>
```

When you use this XSLT stylesheet:

```
 <output xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xsl:version="1.0">
    <xsl:value-of select="/menu/pizzas/@attribute"/>
 </output>
```

This style of stylesheet writing is called a "simplified" stylesheet.  Below is a transcript of the above running in a DOS prompt using Saxon:

```
t:\ftemp>type pizza.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
  <pizzas attribute="CAT">
    <pizza>
        <name>Tomato &amp; Cheese</name>
        <small>5.50</small>
        <large>9.75</large>
    </pizza>
  </pizzas>
</menu>

t:\ftemp>call xslt pizza.xml pizza.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><output>CAT</output>
t:\ftemp>type pizza.xsl 
 <output xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xsl:version="1.0">
    <xsl:value-of select="/menu/pizzas/@attribute"/>
 </output>

t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

So, in fact, you don't need `<xsl:stylesheet>` and `<xsl:template>` for the simple requirements that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid - missing closing tags for `pizzas` and `menu`. Be careful with copy and paste!
If you have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
  <pizzas attribute="CAT">
    <pizza>
        <name>Tomato &amp; Cheese</name>
        <small>5.50</small>
        <large>9.75</large>
    </pizza>
  </pizzas>
</menu>
```

and you apply this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <output>
    <xsl:value-of select="/menu/pizzas/@attribute"/>
 </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>CAT</output>
```

Comment: sorry but do i have to put the `xsl:stylesheet` and the `xsl:template` for the `xsl:value-of` to work?

Comment: Technically you could just say `<output xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0"><xsl:value-of select="/menu/pizzas/@attribute"/></output>` and it would be a valid XSLT file ([XSLT 1.0 spec §2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#result-element-stylesheet)), but that's rarely appropriate in real life because you can't then use things like `<xsl:output>` or `<xsl:strip-space>`